# Problem starting Passenger with Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have just setup Passenger with Nginx and it seems to install fine but when I run it I try to start it by:

```
passenger start -e production
```

I get:

```
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /root/rails_apps/myapp/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /root/rails_apps/myapp/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
===============================================================================
2011/04/18 07:17:27 [error] 9125#0: *4 "/root/rails_apps/myapp/public/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
```

and I get "Unable to connect" when I try to access my site in the browser.

Here is configuration in nginx.conf

```
   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name myapp.com;
      root /root/rails_apps/myapp/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
      passenger_enabled on;
   }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo passenger start -e production
```

Comment: try changing permission of `/root/rails_apps/myapp/public` directory to 755.

Comment: @Surya  Changing it to 755 is a bad idea, it would work but its not ideal for a production environment. You probably just need to chown the files in question to nginx:nginx or whichever use is running nginx while leaving the files 644.

Answer (score 3):

This error seems caused because the user of nginx cannot access the mentioned file. It can be caused not only if the /root/rails_apps/myapp/public is not have a correct permission, but even if one of the **parent directories** does not have that!

In your nginx.conf you can see something like:

```
user nginx;

http {
    # blah.
}
```

Sometimes parameter of the `user` can be different. Be sure to *all* folder is available by this user in the path.
You can check it by `sudo -Hu nginx /bin/bash -l` and `cat /root/rails_apps/myapp/public/index.html`. Test and test it again with this command until you cannot see the content of the file.

A little explanation: with that sudo command you start a shell as an user *nginx*. And with `cat` command you can simulate the file reading.

Answer (score 1):

since the path you specified is in /root (/root/rails_apps/myapp/public), nginx should have enough permissions:

`user  root`; in nginx.conf

you should also start nginx as superuser ( sudo )

but it might be better to just move your rails app somewhere to your user directory and grant needed permissions to default nginx user 'www-data'

```
user www-data;
```

Comment: I'm running as root! do I still need to do that?